# @login_required view decorator only accepts superuser in Django test

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, decorator

In a Django unit test using `TestCase` I want to POST data to a view that has the `@login_required` decorator.

**test_views.py**:

```
class ExportQuestionnaireTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(
            username='jose', email='jose@test.com', password='passwd'
        )

        # self.user.is_superuser = True
        # self.user.save()

        self.client.login(username=self.user.username, password='passwd')

    def test_same_questionnaire_used_in_different_steps_return_correct_content(self):
       data = {
           'per_participant': 'on',
           'action': 'run'
       }

       response = self.client.post(reverse('export_view'), data)
```

**views.py**:

```
@login_required
def export_view(request, template_name="export/export_data.html"):
    export_form = ExportForm()
    ...
```

As can be seen in `test_views.py`, I'm creating a user and logged in through `self.client.login`, then POSTing to the view. When running the test, the request doesn't achieve the view.

But when I uncomment the two lines in `test_views.py` (i. e., make `self.user` superuser), the request achieves the view (verified that debbuging with Pycharm).

What could be the reason?

Comment: Try just uncommenting the `self.user.save()` line.

Comment: Does not solve. `create_user` already saves.

Comment: Your code should work as is. I would suggest removing the `@login_required` decorator and checking if your test then passes with a regular user.

Comment: On a side note, you might want to use `self.client.login(username=self.user.username, ...)`. Currently your code relies on the fact the `str(self.user) == 'jose'`

Comment: Thanks @DanielHepper, I just updated the post. Now what happens when drop `@login_required`: without `@login_required` and with logging in: do not enter in view; without `@login_required` and without logging in: does enter the view. So this is unclear for me either. :-(

Comment: Is this a plain view that is directly hooked into a URL pattern? Does it have any extra decorators not shown here? Do you have any custom middlewares installed?

Comment: It was a custom middleware @DanielHepper. I found it here. Thanks for the tip. As this question does not have public sense anymore I think I can delete it ok?

Comment: You can write an answer yourself and accept it. Someone else might stumble upon it and find it useful